# Rails 4 app - trying to update "badges" values in the navigation bar using AJAX and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views, setinterval

I havea rails 4 app which uses bootstrap. My navigation bar looks like this:

![enter image description here][1]

These are rendered using a partial called from the following code in "layouts/application.html.erb"

```
 <div id="badge_refresh" class="container-fluid nav-collapse">
<%= render "layouts/badges"%> <%# partial _badges.html.erb %> 
 </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

partial= "_badges.html.erb"

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
 <li class="label label-info"><span class="badge pull-right"></span><%= link_to "Tasks", tasks_url %></li>
 <li>" "</li>
 <li class="label label-info"><span class="badge pull-right"><%= Upload.where.not(:status => [ 2, -1, 0]).count%></span><%= link_to "Uploads", uploads_url %></li>
     <li>" "</li>
     <li class="label label-info"><span class="badge pull-right"><%=Channel.all.count%></span><%= link_to "Channels", channels_url  %></li>
     <li>" "</li>
......
```

The  I added a file "refresh_badges.js.erb" with the following contents:

```
 $('#badge_refresh').html("<%= escape_javascript render 'layouts/badges' %>");
```

This setup renders the navigation bar fine. However, what Im trying to do is refresh the badge values every few seconds. So I am trying to understand how to do that using the setInterval method that I know is able to do polling.

My question is how will that code look and where should I put it? Should it be put in the "application.js"? or should I create a new file under "javascripts" folder.

Im new to AJAX and rails so trying to learn here by doing. Any help you guys give would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function refreshBadge(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/controller/refresh_badges',
    format: 'js'
  })
}

setInterval(refreshBadge, 1000);
```

This can be called from application.js or application.html.erb

Comment: Hey thanks, but there is not URL to be called. The function just needs to call the render partial function every 1 second

Comment: @banditKing you need to have at least an empty controller action

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new js file as usually in rails application.js is used as a manifest file

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({url: "your url "})
},3000);
```

Now rails render refresh_badges.js.erb and update the content

Comment: There is no url here to be pinged. The AJAX function simply needs to render the partial _badges.html.erb every 1 second.

Comment: without hitting server how you are thinking to get the information.

Comment: Thats a good point you guys. Sorry, Im a newbie I understand it better now. Thanks.